How to get Request object in route decorator?
How to get a request object in the decorator without specifying it explicitly in route? I already have a lot routers, I don't want to put request: Request in each one.
How it works:
def decorator_func(...):
    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        async def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
            return await func(args, kwargs)

        return wrapper

    return decorator


@router.get(path='/something')
@decorator_func(...)
def get_something(request: Request):
    ...

What I want:
def decorator_func(...):
    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        async def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            request = ... # GET request object
            return await func(args, kwargs)

        return wrapper

    return decorator


@router.get(path='/something')
@decorator_func(...)
def get_something(...):
    ...


Could you use a dependency instead? That would allow you to define request: Request as one of the required parameters, and FastAPI would fill it in automagically for you when calling your dependency.

@MatsLindh I don't want to add a request: Request in each route, because request: Request is unused

Yes, which is why I suggested using a dependency: @router.get(path='/something', dependencies=[my_other_func]), with def my_other_func(request: Request) - which would be your inner function in this case. You can use yield in the dependency to have code run before/after the invocation of the endpoint, and you can use dependencies on the router base level if you want to apply it to all routes in a router (if you want to apply it for all requests, use a middleware)

@МатсЛинд I did not fully understand, can you please express your thoughts in the form of an answer with a pseudo-code

Does this answer your question?

You can use the dependencies parameter to the route decorator to have specific dependencies invoked as part of your request flow, in particular when you're not going to use their return value.
By using yield inside the dependency you can have code run before and after the controller has been invoked:
from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI, Request


app = FastAPI()


def conditional_dependency(request: Request):
    print(f"I'm before request {request}")
    yield 
    print(f"I'm after request {request}")


@app.get(path='/something', dependencies=[Depends(conditional_dependency)])
def get_something():
    print("This is the request itself")

This results in the output:
I'm before request <starlette.requests.Request object at 0x0000021686F75240>
This is the request itself
I'm after request <starlette.requests.Request object at 0x0000021686F75240>

When the endpoint is invoked.
This is also useful when you want to apply specific functionality to the router as a whole (but not to other routers in your application):
from fastapi import APIRouter, Depends, FastAPI, Request


app = FastAPI()


def conditional_dependency(request: Request):
    print(f"I'm before request {request}")
    yield 
    print(f"I'm after request {request}")


router_with_dependency = APIRouter(
    dependencies=[Depends(conditional_dependency)]
)

app.mount('/foo', router_with_dependency)


@router_with_dependency.get(path='/something')
def get_something():
    print("This is the request itself")

Making a request to /foo/something will have the dependency run for every endpoint registered with that router, while endpoints registered on the application object or other routers won't have it invoked automagically.

and how do I pass the request object to the decorator? that's my main problem

That's why I asked whether you actually need a decorator or not; this is a way to solve the requirement of invoking specific code before and after an endpoint gets executed. If you actually need to have a decorator, then this isn't a solution to that - but it might be a solution to the problem you're trying to solve with the decorator. FastAPI's dependencies are usually used where other frameworks would use decorators instead.

Expanding on Mats' answer, if the data you want to pass is constant you can wrap the decorator in a factory function, then you have both request and data at the same time:
def dep_with_data(data: str):
    def conditional_dependency(request: Request):
        print(f"I'm before request {request}, data is {data}")
        yield
        print(f"I'm after request {request}, data is {data}")
    return conditional_dependency


@app.get(path='/something', dependencies=[Depends(dep_with_data("something"))])
def get_something():
    print("This is the request itself")


@app.get(path='/another', dependencies=[Depends(dep_with_data("another thing"))])
def get_another():
    print("This is the request itself")

If that is the only dependency you need to pass you can move more stuff to the wrapper to shorten the code each time you use it:
def dep_with_data(data: str):
    def conditional_dependency(request: Request):
        print(f"I'm before request {request}, data is {data}")
        yield
        print(f"I'm after request {request}, data is {data}")
    return {
        "dependencies": [Depends(conditional_dependency)]
    }


@app.get(path='/something', **dep_with_data("something"))
def get_something():
    print("This is the request itself")


@app.get(path='/another', **dep_with_data("another thing"))
def get_another():
    print("This is the request itself")

